# Python asynchronous method

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm having trouble with async methods. I've already tried many examples from stack overflow, such as:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(method())
loop.close()

-----------

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [  
    asyncio.ensure_future(method()),
    asyncio.ensure_future(method()),
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))  
loop.close()
```

The problem with those approaches is that they need to specify the number/methods before executing. What I need is a way to call a specific method many times from the terminal, but it can't be stuck on the last call.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a specific method many times"? The same method or different methods? Also, how will you be calling these functions from the terminal?

Comment: Let's say that I have a void method and it takes around 30s to process. I would like to call it from terminal by typing it, but each time I don't want to wait it finish before call the same method again. It can be done in C# as a background worker, but I don't know how to do in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def printRandomNumber():
    print(random.randint(0, 100)) # output a random number 0-100
    time.sleep(30) # pause 30 seconds

FUNCS = {
    'foo': printRandomNumber
}

def createWorker(name):
    func = FUNCS.get(name, lambda: None)
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target = func, name = name)
    process.start()

while True:
    func_name = input('next function name: ')
    createWorker(func_name)
```

When executed, you can type "foo" and `printRandomNumber` will run in the background. You can, of course, change `"foo"` to whatever you like (like `"printRandomNumber"`), and with a little work, you could even get some arguments working.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help.